# Refactored way of titleizing values from a model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, model

I have trouble thinking of a way on how to shorten my process on titleizing values upon rendering them in my view.

I did some custom getters for the following attributes that I need to titleize. Here's my example.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def department
        read_attribute(:department).titleize
    end

    def designation
        read_attribute(:designation).titleize
    end
end
```

This method works but it seems a hassle when I want to do this to other models as well.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this which can be used by other models? If you'll mention `Draper` (since I don't seem to find on how to titleize selected attributes), how can I accomplish using this gem? But, I would prefer not using a gem but instead, create a custom one.

Comment: Do you want to `titleize` values just for showing to users or for some other operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested this, but you could use a [Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) with added modules to handle it

--

**Modularity**

I found a gem called [`modularity`](https://github.com/makandra/modularity) which basically allows you to pass parameters to a `concern` & other modules. This means if you can pass the params you wish to "titleize", you may be able to pull it off like this:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'modularity', '~> 2.0.1'

#app/models/concerns/titleize.rb
module Titleize
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   as_trait do |*fields|
     fields.each do |field|

        define_method("#{field}") do
           self[field.to_sym] = field.titleize
        end

     end
   end

end

#app/models/your_model.rb
Class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Titleize[:your, :params]
end
```

Comment: does this affect when i'm saving/updating records? or only works for reading?

Comment: Reading, as per your question :) You can adapt for saving if you want

Comment: it doesn't seem to work inside the `define_method` block, i tried `self[field.to_sym].titleize` only for that line, but it seems to reject since those attributes are only accepting values in lowercase. i could modify the records and the model respectively to accept titleized values, but i think it would take me long. any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

If you want those value always titleized, what you are doing is fine, but I would actually apply the method on the setters, not on the getters, so you only do it once per record instead of at each read:

```
def department=(s)
  write_attribute(:department, s.to_s.titleize) # The to_s is in case you get nil/non-string
end
```

If this is purely for presentation (ie, you want the not titleized version in the database, then it can be done in a presenter using Draper:

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def designation
    object.designation.titleize
  end
end
```

(or another [rails presenter](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters)).

Comment: I guess @oLrax don't want to write this code for each attributes, he may wants something global